# Since when are you here ? Is it correct?

Tags: time

Is it correct to ask , since when are you here ?
I came three hours ago 
I'm here for 3 house
Or I'm here since 10 o'clock .

Can I ask this question for someone who is just at that place for 3 house , or since the morning  How long have you been here ?

Comment: Please show us what research you have done. Try looking up the use of since in sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: No, it is not correct to say "Since when are you here?" in English.

"Since when have you been here?" Is grammatically correct, but not common and will sound weird to native English speakers (at least in North America).

In casual speech, it is more common to say "When did you get here?"

If you want to be a little more formal, then "When did you arrive?"